# Invalid argument supplied for foreach in magento Front controller

Tags: magento

I have the next error:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()  in app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php on line 133
```

I found out this error arises in method `init` because of

```
Mage::app()->getStore()->getConfig(self::XML_STORE_ROUTERS_PATH)
```

returns null. 
I tried clear the cache but without success.

Comment: In which context does this error occur? Browser? CLI? Magento or custom action? Which URL is used?

Comment: I have already found the answer. In my case cause of the error was empty field in `core_config_data` table. I'm wonder from where it was appeared there.

Comment: We had the same problem after an admin changed an (arbitrary) config value. It turned out it was memcached which had an invalid entry in its cache.